# Alternatives to the MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns

What are the alternative "design methods" to the Model View Controller? MVC seems to be popular (SO was built with it, I know that much) but is it the only method used?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There are many others:

- [Model View Presenter (MVP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_Presenter)

  - [Supervising Controller](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaDev/SupervisingPresenter.html)
  - [Passive View](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PassiveScreen.html)
- [Model View ViewModel (MVVM)](http://www.orbifold.net/default/?p=550)

  - This is common in WPF applications (though [Prism](http://www.codeplex.com/CompositeWPF) uses the MVP pattern (usually))

Comment: Not really alternatives, more variations on a theme, +1 for links

Answer (score 54):

One of the best write-ups of several different Interactive Application Architecture Patterns out there, is [this very detailed and well-researched blog-post](https://web.archive.org/web/20201107060523/https://lostechies.com/derekgreer/2007/08/25/interactive-application-architecture/). It covers Model-View-Controller, three different flavors of Model-View-Presenter, several different flavors of Presentation-Abstraction-Control, Supervising Controller, Passive View and Hierarchical MVC.

Another interesting pattern is the [Presenter First](https://atomicobject.com/resources/presenter-first) pattern by Atomic Objects. It's not just a Design Pattern, it's also a Process Pattern. IOW: the name "Presenter First" is not arbitrary, it actually describes a development process, in which the Presenter gets written first, driving the design of the rest of the system.

Answer (score 21):

MVC is an architectural pattern. These are the other Architectural patterns you can try (from Wikipedia):

- Layers
- Multi-tier Architecture
- Presentation Abstraction Control (PAC)
- Model View Presenter (MVP)
- Model View ViewModel (MVVM)
- Pipeline
- Implicit Invocation
- Blackboard System
- Peer-to-Peer
- Service Oriented Architecture (SOA)
- Naked Objects

These are available [here in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architectural_pattern_%28computer_science%29).

Answer (score 8):

**DCI** - "Data, Communication and Interaction"

http://www.antonioshome.net/kitchen/nbdci/index.php#dci-introduction

http://www.artima.com/articles/dci_visionP.html

[The Common Sense of Object Orientated Programming](http://folk.uio.no/trygver/2008/commonsense.pdf) - MVC vs DCI

Comment: DCI **is** an aternative to MVC. What's with the down vote?

Comment: DCI is a compliment to MVC, not an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

MVC is part of a greater group of design patterns. I have no idea how much experience you have, so I'm not sure how to target this response. I'm a .NET programmer, but I found the Java book [Head First Design Patterns](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596007126/) extremely helpful. Design patterns are usually broken into groups with other patterns that help solve similar problems.

I also found the [Data Object Factory website](http://www.dofactory.com) quite helpful as well. You should look around for some resources in your favorite language.

Comment: As an aside, I read the Head First book as a c# programmer, and the examples were easy enough to understand without Java experience.

Answer (score 2):

I know the [**MVCS**](http://joeberkovitz.com/blog/reviewtube/) from Joe Berkovitz.

Prof. Kowarschick used that approach to develop the [**VCLSD**](http://glossar.hs-augsburg.de/Logic-Data-View-Controller-Service-Paradigma)-Pattern (Wiki written in german! Maybe someone has time, to translate it - as for myself I am only a beginner in programming)

MVCS: Model View Control Service
VCLSD: View Control Logic Service Data

Answer (score 2):

How about flux.js from Facebook? I know it's platform dependent, but it's a data flow architecture used by FB as a replacement for MVC, so I believe you can get some ideas from there too.

Answer (score 1):

We use not so much an alternative but a hybrid called [MVC-ARS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140098/is-mvc-ars-preferable-to-classic-mvc-to-prevent-overloading).