# What application architectures existing except MVC?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, model-view-controller, architecture

Right now im writing ASP.NET Core application and i've been thinking about type of project like ASP.NET Core MVC and then ask myself is there another architectures except MVC existing?

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Open-ended questions are too broad and therefore off-topic.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141912/alternatives-to-the-mvc here is another helpful link for being new to stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Note: that question is very old and wasn't considered off-topic at the time. It was posted in 2008 but not closed as too broad / needs more focus until 2016. Such questions are retained for historical reasons but that doesn't mean they're on topic for new questions.